# Docking Control Bar in MFC

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I have 3 docking control bars with following alignments left, right and bottom. You can get example from this link 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6/CSizingControlBar-A-Resizable-Control-Bar

[image: controlbars_image]

I got the sample of dockablepanes  with following alignments left, right and bottom from the link

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493218/Understanding-CDockablePane

[image: DockablePanes_image]

In dockablepane, the dockable pane with bottom alignment is placed/aligned automatically between left and right pane whereas, in docking control bars the bar with bottom alignment is always occupies whole width of the application I am not  able to place it between left and right bars.

In docking controlbars I want to place the bar with bottom alignment, between the left and right bar.

How to achieve my requirement with docking controlbars ?

Comment: It depends on the order you Dock them. If you swap the order you Dock them, you will see changes. Note there may be a cache on your Windows Registry about previous dockable controls' placement. I had similar problems a while ago and it was the solution I found.

Comment: @seigrol, when docking first time I want to place the bar with bottom alignment, between the left and right bar.My docking order is first left bar , then right bar , then bottom bar.